# Sigil Strings in Magento 2's RequireJS Files

Tags: magento2, javascript, requirejs

I've noticed strange-to-me "sigil strings" strewn throughout Magento 2's RequireJS modules.  Here's one example.

```
return Element.extend({
    defaults: {
        clientConfig: {
            urls: {
                save: '${ $.submit_url }',
                beforeSave: '${ $.validate_url }'
            }
        }
    },
```

Does anyone know what these strings (`${ $.submit_url }`, `${ $.validate_url }`) are for?  Is it some Magento meta-programming language?   Or are they something executed in Knockout.js context?  Or something else?

Comment: It's used by jQuery Template Plugin - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13907924/javascript-followed-by-curly-braces

Comment: @BartekIgielski Are you sure that's what it is in Magento 2?  There's two nested level of sigils. I don't see that in your link.

Comment: Sorry, I though they use it, but looks like there is a Magento custom implementation of Underscore.js templating engine created in `lib/web/mage/utils/template.js` and some kind of documentation is inside that file. Hope that may help you somehow :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

They are [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) that Magento handles itself to enhance browser compatibility.

In ES2015, template literals can be done with back-ticks (``` `` ```). However, since not all browsers support that, Magento opted to process them by itself. This is done upon initialization of Javascript components in the `mage/utils/template.js` file. Specifically, the `initConfig()` method of `lib/core/class.js` transfers the `defaults` property into class properties and runs the `template()` method on each one.

If the browser supports ES2015-style template literals, then Magento simply uses backticks to process the string. If not, it manually evaluates the expression.

The expression inside the `${ }` (`$.submit_url` in your example), is evaluated as a key from the config data that is passed into the JSON representing the UI Component. From what I've seen, this is usually declared in the form of `js_config` or just `config` in an XML `<argument />` node (see [ui_component/category_form.xml](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/ui_component/category_form.xml#L34)).

They are evaluated in KnockoutJS context with the `$` representing the Knockout object that relates to that component.

<sub>*Sidenote*: I just [wrote some information on that](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_data_source.html#javascript-template-literals) in a topic that I created a PR for the devdocs on.</sub>

Comment: Thanks @bassplayer7 -- super helpful.  It's also worth noting that the `$.submit_url` variable/placeholder inside the `${}` variable/placeholder markers is **not** (to my knowledge) standard ES 6 template literal code, and instead an addition Magento made that's able to read from a bound object of view variables (from the constructor's defaults), or an object passed into the constructor at instantiation time.

Comment: @AlanStorm, glad it was helpful. My understanding is that expressions inside template literals [can be just about anything](https://css-tricks.com/template-literals/#article-header-id-1), though. Magento makes the `$ ` reference the Knockout context and, as a result, when Javascript evaluates the expression, it accesses the `submit_url` property of the `$` variable.

Comment: Its my understanding the ES6  placeholders can us any variable in the current scope.  Magento's literals, implemented by the `mage/utils/template` RequireJS library, can only read form the global scope, **or** from a specific bound object. i.e.  (requirejs('mage/utils/template').template(`${$.foo}`, {'foo':'hello!'}).  Magento binds the second argument as `$` inside the placeholder.  So it's probably more accurate for me to say Magento's use of ES6 literals is standard, but they've (at some level) created a new system that extends their capabilities into non-standard territory.