# How do "imports" work in a ui-component?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I've seen [this `customizeNameListeners` method](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier/General.php#L300) in the product add/edit form modifier.

Inside it, there is an array that contains a member called `imports`

```
    'imports' => [
                'handleNameChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.name',
                'handleDescriptionChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.description',
                'handleSkuChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.sku',
                'handleColorChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.color',
                'handleCountryChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.country_of_manufacture',
                'handleGenderChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.gender',
                'handleMaterialChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.material',
                'handleShortDescriptionChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.short_description',
                'handleSizeChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.size'
            ],
```

I understand that its purpose is to modify on the fly field values depending on other field values. For example, when adding a product, the SKU is filled in automatically from the product name value.
I also understand that this

```
'handleNameChanges' => '${$.provider}:data.product.name',
```

means that the function `handleNameChanges` from the [`import-handled.js`](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/view/adminhtml/web/js/components/import-handler.js#L36) is called and receives the parameter `'${$.provider}:data.product.name'`.

What I don't understand is how is this all bound together and how `${$.provider}:data.product.name` is parsed.
How/where is the change event (or onkeyup or anything else) is bound to the name field?

Comment: I'm not sure it will answer your question, but please check http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/ui-components/ui_components_js.html#comp_link. There's some info about  "imports" and other properties used for linking.

Comment: I've read that. That's where I got the idea that this might be used to track changes and take different actions based on the changes, but I don't understand how it's all bound together.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138936/what-are-the-import-exports-defaults-for-in-a-uielement-object/139168#139168