# Magento 2: Are uiClass/uiElement Imports/Exports order sensitive?

Tags: javascript, uicomponent, uielement

Magento's uiClass/uiElement objects [have a feature](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/138936/what-are-the-import-exports-defaults-for-in-a-uielement-object) that allow them, at the time of instantiation, to populate a property of their own (`imports`) from a `uiRegistry` registered object, or populate a property from another object (`exports`) from a third `uiRegistry` object.

What's not clear from the implementation is

- Are there `imports`/`exports` sensitive the the order components are loaded? (i.e. naive implementation)
- Or will the property "linking" functionality retry until it finds a registered object in the `uiRegistry`
- Or is the "link" lazy loaded?
- Does this behavior change if the uiClass/uiElement objects are used stand-alone vs. being used in a `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` application

I'd assume a naive implementation -- but there's a lot of javascript promise use and deferred callback loading going on in `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` that's not easy to follow.  That, plus poor documentation of how the object system works or its intent makes this difficult to know for sure without fully unspooling a `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` app.

I'm hoping someone already has the answer and can spare me that code dive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This functionality is implemented in the "links" module.  When this module fetches items from the registry

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/lib/core/element/links.js
registry.get(data.target, function (target) {
    args.unshift(target);

    setLink.apply(null, args);
});
```

it uses the `get(index, callback)` syntax.  This syntax ensure the callback will not be called (and therefore the values not set) [until an item exists in the registry](http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/154437392745/using-the-uiregistry-asynchronously-and-safely).

This functionality is independent of the `Magento_Ui/js/core/app` application.  Its reliant on the callback querying features of the `uiRegistry` module.