# How to share Knockout JS observables between UI Components

Tags: magento2, javascript, uicomponent, knockoutjs, requirejs

I understand how to use [`imports: {}` and `exports: {}`](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/ui_comp_guide/concepts/ui_comp_linking_concept.html) to share a UI components properties, such as:

```
defaults: {
    exports: {
        shouldShowMessage: '${$.component}'
    }
}
```

Which returns the component name in the exports.

[image]

But when I try to export a Knockout observable it is always undefined:

```
defaults: {
    exports: {
        shouldShowMessage: '${$.shouldShowMessage}'
    }
}

...

setupKoBindings: function() {
    this.shouldShowMessage = ko.observable('Testing');
}
```

[image]

As a workaround I am going to create a storage model as explained [here](https://inviqa.com/blog/using-knockout-js-magento-2) but I would prefer to use the imports and exports.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The values of the exports object have to resolve to a name and a property of a  UiComponent instance, separated by a ':', for example `checkout.cart.total:title`.
The export target name has to include the UI component "namespace".

In your example, you set the value to a string, which resolves to a property of the UiComponent that is the export source.
The export is undefined when you inspect it because that is not a valid export target.

Here is an example that works:

```
defaults: {
    exportTarget: "foo.bar",
    exportTargetProperty: "showMessage",

    tracks: {
        shouldShowMessage: true
    },

    exports: {
        shouldShowMessage: '${$.exportTarget}:${$.exportTargetProperty}'
    }
}
...
```

The above will copy the value of the `shouldShowMessage` property into the property `showMessage` of a UiComponent with the full name `foo.bar` every time the value changes.
Note that this will not automatically make the target property a KO observable, too. That has to be declared explicitly, if value changes should trigger KO to rerender DOM nodes that access that property.

By the way, adding `shouldShowMessage` to the `tracks` object will make it a ko-es5 observable automagically. Using a literal `ko.observable()` works, too.

In the example above, the `exportTarget` and `exportTargetProperty` are configured in the `defaults`. They also could be specified as part of the UiComponent options in the JSON, which usually makes more sense, since that is where the UiComponent hierarchy including the UiComponent names are defined.

Finally, I would like to note that I personally think your solution using a value object to pass the value to the other UI component is better than using exports or imports. In my experience keeping shared state in the DOM or in UiComponents is a recipe for spaghetti OOP in all but the simplest cases.

Comment: Excellent explanation, thanks @Vinai! I'll give it a try when I have time and mark this as accepted if it works.

Comment: I've run into some issues when using `tracks`, manually subscribing to observables no longer works `this.shouldShowMessage.subscribe is not a function` when using `this.shouldShowMessage.subscribe(function() {
                ...
            });`

It works fine when setting observables any other way. Feels as though I'm missing a step or `tracks` doesn't create an observable the same way.

Comment: You are right, the properties are no longer regular ko observables, just ES5 getter/setter pairs. If you want to access the original observable function you can inject ko and use `ko.getObservable(this, 'shouldShowMessage').subscribe(function(newValue) { ...});` (the first argument is the viewmodel (`this`), the second one the name of the tracked property. More info here: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout-es5

Comment: Ahh that makes sense, you're the best <3

Comment: Awww <3 *blush*

Comment: After playing around with imports and exports and still failing I agree this is spaghetti code, I've given up and I'll stick with manual subscriptions and a storage model.